# Drop a column from composite primarykey

Tags: oracle

i want to drop a column from composite primary key(not to delete from table). if my table is like this.

```
create table "scott"."xyz"(
   "column1" not null,
   "column2" not null,
   "column3" not null,
   "column4" not null,
   "column5" not null,
   "column6",
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY ("column1","column2","column3","column4")
);
```

i want to alter this primary key to first three column without dropping it. beacuse i don't know CONSTRAINT name.

Comment: _Please_ don't use cased table and column names. It is so confusing and means that you have to explicitly quote them everywhere as you are doing. If you don't quote anything then you never have to quote anything (as long as you don't use reserved words).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the constraint name:

```
 ALTER TABLE "scott"."xyz" DROP PRIMARY KEY;
 ALTER TABLE "scott"."xyz" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("column1","column2","column3");
```

But it is probably a good idea to give your PK a name in the future:

```
 ALTER TABLE "scott"."xyz" 
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_xyz PRIMARY KEY ("column1","column2","column3");
```

And I would not recommend to use quoted identifiers. You will have problems with various tools in the long run.

Comment: @mallikarjun: Oracle will automatically drop the corresponding index. See the manual for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#i2103845

Comment: i dropped primary key but if i add new primary key to this table by taking column1 and column2 am getting primary key violation error. i know my table has duplicate data with these column. how to find such a columns